# How to renew wrong SMTP Openssl s_client certificate?

Tags: postfix, vpn, email-server

I dont know where openssl got the certificate but I am pretty sure I generated everything via letsencrypt certbot.

Now, this command displays a wrong certificate CN:

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect a.com:587 -starttls smtp
```

It shows that CN is for domain b.com. How to renew the cert?

Edit:

Please indicate reason for downvote, I am pretty sure the cert was not generated by certbot. The cert CN was not part of the config in certbot.

Comment: Did you restart your SMTP software after the certificate renewal?

Comment: how to renew the certificate? it seems to be coming from nowhere

Comment: If your OpenSSL is below 1.1.1, add `-servername a.com` to your `s_client` command. Also look at the SubjectAlternativeName (SAN) extension in the cert (by piping it to, or storing it in a file and feeding it to, `openssl x509 -noout -text`), which supersedes and overrides CommonName (CN) in subject for nearly all CAs, including LE, since about 2010 -- although LE should still put _one_ of the cert's hostnames in CN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is coming from postfix config using certain certificates. This can be fixed by requesting a new certbot certificate via following command:

```
sudo certbot certonly --standalone -d <your.domain>
```

then using the certificate in the postfix config:

```
sudo postconf -e 'smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/<your.domain>/fullchain.pem'
sudo postconf -e 'smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/letsencrypt/live/<your.domain>/privkey.pem'
```

See here for details: https://upcloud.com/community/tutorials/secure-postfix-using-lets-encrypt/